# Using case_when() within mutate_at() to recode several columns with different types of NA

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, typeerror, na

Given the data:

```
df <- structure(list(cola = structure(c(5L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 
8L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "d", "g", "q", "r", "t", "w", 
"x", "z"), class = "factor"), colb = c(156L, 8L, 6L, 100L, 49L, 
31L, 189L, 77L, 154L, 171L), colc = c(0.207140279468149, 0.51990159181878, 
0.402017514919862, 0.382948065642267, 0.488511856179684, 0.263168515404686, 
0.38591041485779, 0.774066215148196, 0.763264901703224, 0.474355421960354
), cold = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

df
#    cola colb      colc cold
# 1     q  156 0.2071403    a
# 2     x    8 0.5199016    b
# 3     r    6 0.4020175    a
# 4     b  100 0.3829481    b
# 5     t   49 0.4885119    a
# 6     z   31 0.2631685    b
# 7     d  189 0.3859104    a
# 8     w   77 0.7740662    b
# 9     a  154 0.7632649    a
# 10    g  171 0.4743554    b
```

If the value in `colc` in a particular row is `>= 0.5`, I would like to replace the contents of all the other cells in that row with NA, except for the contents of `cold` for that row (which I would like to retain as it is).

I attempted this with `dplyr::mutate_at()` and `base::ifelse()`, and it works fine:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-c(cold)), funs(ifelse(colc >= 0.5, NA, .)))

#    cola colb      colc cold
# 1     5  156 0.2071403    a
# 2    NA   NA        NA    b
# 3     6    6 0.4020175    a
# 4     2  100 0.3829481    b
# 5     7   49 0.4885119    a
# 6    10   31 0.2631685    b
# 7     3  189 0.3859104    a
# 8    NA   NA        NA    b
# 9    NA   NA        NA    a
# 10    4  171 0.4743554    b
```

But I would like to do this with `dplyr::case_when()`, as I might have more than one replacement condition to fulfill (e.g., replace with `"foo"` if `colc < 0.5 & colc >= 0.3`. But `case_when()` does not appear to be playing nice:

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(-c(cold)), funs(case_when(colc >= 0.5 ~ NA, TRUE ~ .)))
```

> Error: must be a logical vector, not a factor object

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? I assume this is because I am trying to convert multiple columns with different data types to NA. I tried to look for a solution online, but I wasn't able to find one.

**Edit:** in specific, I would like to preserve the data types of the various columns as they are.

Comment: Why call `colc` again? Why not use an anon since `colc` is already in the `mutate_at` call?

Comment: This works but not pretty imho: `mutate_at(vars(-cold), ~case_when(colc >= 0.5 ~ NA_integer_,
                                    TRUE ~ as.integer(.x)))`

Comment: @NelsonGon could you please explain what you meant with your first comment?

Comment: It's actually not important. I initially thought checking `colc` against itself was repetitive but later realised `colc` is the reference hence an anon wouldn't work.

Comment: See also [Type conflict setting multiple variables to NA with mutate, across, case_when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658449/type-conflict-setting-multiple-variables-to-na-with-mutate-across-case-when)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-c(cold)), ~ case_when(colc >= 0.5 ~ `is.na<-`(., TRUE), TRUE ~ .))

#    cola colb      colc cold
# 1     q  156 0.2071403    a
# 2  <NA>   NA        NA    b
# 3     r    6 0.4020175    a
# 4     b  100 0.3829481    b
# 5     t   49 0.4885119    a
# 6     z   31 0.2631685    b
# 7     d  189 0.3859104    a
# 8  <NA>   NA        NA    b
# 9  <NA>   NA        NA    a
# 10    g  171 0.4743554    b
```

**Description**

When you use `case_when` to assign `NA`, you need to specify the type of `NA`, i.e. `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_` and `NA_character_`. However, `mutate_at` transforms multiple columns at the same time and these columns have different types, so you cannot apply one statement on all columns. Ideally, there might exist something like `NA_guess` to identify the type, but I don't find that so far. This method is a little tricky. I use `is.na()` to convert the input vector to NAs, and these NAs will be the same type as the input vector. For example:

```
x <- 1:5
is.na(x) <- TRUE ; x
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
class(x)
# [1] "integer"

y <- letters[1:5]
is.na(y) <- TRUE ; y
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
class(y)
# [1] "character"
```

Comment: I was basically thinking along these lines, and I was hoping someone would mention that a `NA_guess` or something of that sort does exist. Really like the use of `is.na()` here.

Answer (score 3):

Work around similar to @NelsonGon :

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
        mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
        mutate_at(vars(-c(cold)), 
                  ~case_when(colc >= 0.5 ~ NA_character_, # ifelse(is.numeric(.), NA_real_, NA_character_), 
                             TRUE ~ .
                  )
        ) %>% 
        mutate(colb = as.numeric(colb),
               colc = as.numeric(colc)
        )

#>    cola colb      colc cold
#> 1     q  156 0.2071403    a
#> 2  <NA> <NA>        NA    b
#> 3     r    6 0.4020175    a
#> 4     b  100 0.3829481    b
#> 5     t   49 0.4885119    a
#> 6     z   31 0.2631685    b
#> 7     d  189 0.3859104    a
#> 8  <NA> <NA>        NA    b
#> 9  <NA> <NA>        NA    a
#> 10    g  171 0.4743554    b
```

Comment: Wouldn't this solution require changing the data types for all the columns back to their original types?

Comment: Good point guessing `colb` is of type character from the `<NA>` typo. I have updated my answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: This method is great. But it’ll have a dilemma if there exist many columns and each has different type. The final mutate command will become bulky.