# Type conflict setting multiple variables to NA with mutate, across, case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, typeerror, na

I would like to use a combination of `mutate`, `across`, and `case_when` to set some cases to `NA` (missing) across multiple variables.

Say I have an indicator variable "vs" flagging cases that should be `NA` for variables "carb" and "gear". I would like to use something like this to set those cases to missing on both those variables at once:

```
data(mtcars) #load mtcars data
mtcars$carb <- as.integer(mtcars$carb) #set to integer,
                                       #for purposes of illustration

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(gear:carb), ~ case_when(vs==1~NA,
                                      T~.)))
```

I would like this to change "gear" and "carb" to `NA` for all cases for which "vs" is equal to 1. However, since carb is an integer and gear is numeric, I run into a type conflict:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
ℹ `..1 = across(c(gear:carb), ~case_when(vs == 1 ~ NA, T ~ .))`.
x must be a logical vector, not a double vector.
```

If I were using `mutate` on each variable individually, I would replace `NA` with `NA_integer_` for 'carb' and `NA` with `NA_real_` for 'gear'. I can't do that here, since the variables contain different types of data.

Is there any way around this, or can I only use `mutate(across())` like this with variables of the same type?

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data, please, using `dput(.)` if able. Please include your expected output given that sample input.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use dput, but I added an example that reproduces the problem using the built-in mtcars data--hope that's ok. And I added my expected output. Thanks!

Comment: How to use `dput`: type in `dput(x)` (or `dput(head(x,10))` or something that is minimal yet encompasses enough of your question's needs), copy the output from that including the leading `structure(`, the trailing/last `)`, and everything in between, then paste into your question into a code-block. (It's actually very simple. The beauty of that function is that it gives us a completely unambiguous view of the data you are using, whereas the normal console printout masks things `factor`, `Date`/`POSIXct`, list-columns, etc. It also is really help when there are spaces in data.

Comment: But ... your use of `mtcars` is equally "easy", helpful, and often *better* than giving us your data, as long as the question can be adequately modeled in the sample dataset. Thanks!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!

Comment: See also [Using case_when() within mutate_at() to recode several columns with different types of NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455585/using-case-when-within-mutate-at-to-recode-several-columns-with-different-ty)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be to use an `if` statement:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars$carb <- as.integer(mtcars$carb)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(gear:carb), ~ case_when(
    vs == 1 ~ if (is.integer(.)) NA_integer_ else NA_real_,
    T ~ .
  )))
```

But the much more clever approach I learned thanks to the comment by @r2evans would be use `.[NA]` which "will always give the appropriate `NA` type":

```r
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(gear:carb), ~ case_when(
    vs == 1 ~ .[NA],
    T ~ .
  )))

head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1   NA   NA
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0   NA   NA
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0   NA   NA
```

Comment: Shortcut: `vs == 1 ~ .[NA]` will always give the appropriate `NA`-type in class-sensitive funcs like `if_else` and `case_when`. (On occasion I've needed to use `.[NA][1]`.) It's only a *little* bit faster, but I think the code-golf outweighs the verbosity of the `if (is.integer(.))` as well as function-stack overhead.

Comment: @r2evans. Thx. This is really useful, if not brilliant. (; Actually I wrote myself a custom function which uses multiple `if`s to get the right type. :D

Comment: I started down that path some time ago as well, until I realized that checking each class (including `inherits(., "POSIXt")` and `inherits(., "Date")`) adds to the stack and runtime. In the realization that there are at least 6 types of `NA`, I realized there is likely a 7th out there that I didn't know, and therefore `.[NA]` was actually using an already built-in mechanism in R to do it directly: `\`[\`` is unambiguous in that in every class I've come across. So I use it now as a future-proof in case I missed something. And I haven't look back since :-)

Comment: In one of my packages, I even hard-coded constants for `NA_POSIXt_` and `NA_Date_`.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for providing this insight!  I've encountered situations before where I want to `mutate()` `across()` several columns of different types, and perform a type-specific operation on each; yet I've been stymied by the requirement by `case_when()` and `if_else()` that the results all be homogeneous in type.  A frequent font of frustration.

Comment: @stefan: to squeak a little more speed out of this, we can benefit from vectorization a little with `if_else(vs == 1, .[NA], .)`.

Comment: @Greg, "stymied" is certainly one reaction. Another, though, is that `base::ifelse` is rather evil in what it will ***silently*** do. For instance, `ifelse(c(T,T), 1:2, c("a","b"))` will return `integer`, whereas if either condition is not true then it will return `character`. Silently. If/when you write something that is non-interactive and class-sensitive, then these "oops" moments will haunt you, and troubleshooting them can be perplexing. So I counter your "stymied" with ... the class-sensitivity is actually helping you. (However, I wonder if int/num would be close enough to not err...)

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't know about .[NA] - thank you so much!

Comment: Neither did I: @r2evans deserves the credit for teaching us this useful trick.

Comment: @Elizabeth I don't think `.[NA]` is a formal thing, but I believe it to be safe enough that perhaps it should be an "informal standard". I'm not about to promote it to the "R community" until I've had a few more years of testing and confirming ;-)

Comment: @r2evans Oh, I certainly appreciate the tidy enforcement of consistency.  However, ensuring that `col_1` remains consistent with *itself* is entirely different from ensuring that it remains consistent with *all* of {`col_1`, `col_2`, ..., `col_n`}.

Comment: None of what I've looked at here is attempting to enforce consistency with other columns, always with just itself. (At least, that's what my diatribe about `ifelse` was about.)

Comment: @r2evans Regarding "I don't think `.[NA]` is a formal thing": because **NAs in indexing** is described in `?Extract` - "When extracting, a numerical, logical or character `NA` index picks an unknown element and so _returns `NA`_ in the corresponding element of a _logical, integer, numeric, complex or character_ result" - I would call it rather formal. If I understood you correctly ;) Another 'coercion method' in a similar setting can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456413). Cheers

Comment: I think I like `.[NA]` better :-)

Comment: @r2evans Yes, it is very elegant.